# Team Foundation Server 2005 and SQL Express 2005

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2005-express

I haven't seen anything that says SQL Express 2005 is not supported for use with Team Foundation Server 2005.

However, when I attempt the installation I get all sorts of errors "SQL Agent service not installed", "SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services service is not installed", etc.

Is SQL Server Standard or higher, required?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: Doesn't TFS 2005 come with a license for SQL Server Standard edition for use with TFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server Standard or higher is required for current versions of TFS.  When you purchase a full copy of Team Foundation Server it comes with a restricted use SQL Standard Edition license under the following terms:

- You may only use the SQL Server
  software with Visual Studio Team
  Foundation Server;  you may not use
  it for any other purpose.
- You may
  only install SQL Server on one
  physical device per Visual Studio
  Team  Foundation Server license.

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL Server Express Advanced edition ... ( I don't remember if it has analysis services)
Analysis services are required to generate reports. Also after installation of 2005 remember to start SQL Agent service.