# What are the SQL Server requirements for Team Foundation Server And Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting, tfs

I had many problems installing Team Foundation Server 2005 (Workgroup) about six months ago for various reasons, and because other projects have taken priority, I never did finish. On top of that, we are installing a new server and I am now trying to determine what licensing and editions we need to purchase for SQL Server.

One of the problems that I ran into is that Team Foundation Server seemed to require the use of Reporting Services and I was under the impression that I could only use the Reporting Services with the Enterprise version of SQL Server 2005. So, I have some questions and this time we'll "probably" be using SQL Server 2008 and Team Foundation Server 2008.

1. When installing the work group version of Team System 2008, do I have to have Reporting Services installed on that machine?
2. Is Reporting Services only available for SQL Server Enterprise?
3. Basically, can we install Team Foundation Server and have it work with SQL Server Standard?
4. What other gotchas should we consider prior to installing TFS?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have not been able to find any limitation of the Workgroup Edition with regards to the database server. So as far as I know, no, Reporting services does not have to be on the same machine.
2. Reporting Services is available for ALL editions of SQL Server, including the free SQL Server Express, although according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941030/team-foundation-server-2005-and-sql-express-2005) here, SQL Server Standard is the minimal required version
3. Yes.
4. You can find the latest installation guide [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=79226):